# Android custom TextView ignoring edges of layout

Tags: android

**My application needs to rotate a Textview inside a calendar view that is scrollable. The problem is that after scrolling the inside layout it bypass the edges. Rotate a static Textview is simple but how can I solve this drawing problem? Thanks!**

[image]

My custom TextView code is:

```
public class VerticalTextView extends TextView {

    final boolean topDown;

    public VerticalTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        final int gravity = getGravity();
        if (Gravity.isVertical(gravity)
                && (gravity & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK) == Gravity.BOTTOM) {
            setGravity((gravity & Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK)
                    | Gravity.TOP);
            topDown = false;
        } else
            topDown = true;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        return super.setFrame(l, t, l + (b - t), t + (r - l));
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

        if (topDown) {
            canvas.translate(getWidth(), 0);
            canvas.rotate(90);
        } else {
            canvas.translate(0, getHeight());
            canvas.rotate(-90);
        }

        canvas.clipRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(),
                android.graphics.Region.Op.REPLACE);
        super.draw(canvas);

    }
}
```

Using:
`View.setRotation(270);` or `View.setRotation(-90);`
The light gray area is the TextView. As you can see it didn´t stretched to the entire white area.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a much easier way to rotate a `TextView` - just call [`View.setRotation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation(float))! Then you won't need to deal with a custom `TextView` at all.

Comment: Regarding impacts of increasing minSdkVersion to 11 (or really, 15, since there are basically essentially no users on 11-14), check out this dashboard: http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: As for multiline problems, try enabling `android:singleLine="true"` on your `TextView`.

Comment: My minSdkVersion is not 11 @Daniel Lew , I have to check the impacts of his change. But when I use View.setRotation() the text tends to occupy more than one line, seams like my TextView is not using all the space.

Comment: I can change to level 11, no problem on that. But you saw the side effect of the change? It seamns the TextView is not stretching as it should.

Comment: How should it be stretching? I'm not clear on what exactly you want it to look like.

Comment: With a custom TextView the light gray area is larger, but after scrolling it bypass the edges. With setRotation() the TextView seams to be smaller then it should. Hope you have a clue @Daniel Lew thanks a lot!!

Comment: I don't really have time to chat about the extended problem. I'm alright answering the immediate problem of "how do I rotate my TextView" but I don't have time to debug this entire screen. My guess is that it has to do with layout parameters (or maybe the scrolling calendar is acting badly).

Comment: Ok @Daniel Lew, thanks. The original question é "Android custom TextView ignoring edges of layout" and setRotation() still makes it crop the text so it it ao incomplete solution to the original problem.